# How to find out the series of configuration that a Turing machine enters when started on the string 10#10?

Tags: turing-machines

The language is given by: 
B = {w#w | w is an element of {0,1}*}. 
and the state diagram: 
http://oi57.tinypic.com/iqlzdy.jpg

So far, this is what I've got:

`(q1)10#10; x(q3)0#10; x0(q3)#10; x0#(q5)10`

I'm a bit confused with which state it's supposed to enter next.